# Transforming Java.io.BufferedReader into Python object

Tags: java, python, azure, hdfs

by using the following code (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/python/hdfs-to-read-files)

```
URI = sc._gateway.jvm.java.net.URI
Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
FileSystem = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
conf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()

conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key.<account-name>.blob.core.windows.net,
  "<account-access-key>")

fs = Path('wasbs://<container-name>@<account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<file-path>/').getFileSystem(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
istream = fs.open(Path('wasbs://<container-name>@<account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<file-path>/'))

reader = sc._gateway.jvm.java.io.BufferedReader(sc._jvm.java.io.InputStreamReader(istream))

while True:
  thisLine = reader.readLine()
  if thisLine is not None:
    print(thisLine)
  else:
    break

istream.close()
```

**I receive object reader of type java.io.BufferedReader, that I would like to use to read by pandas, geopandas or other libraries (not read and print line by line as in the example).**

Could you help me?

Thank you
Lukas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to read `BufferedReader` content into a string and than read this string with `pd.read_csv(StringIO(string))`:

```
string = reader.lines().collect(sc._jvm.java.util.stream.Collectors.joining())
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(string))
```

Comment: Hi Alexandra, thanks for answer, I tried this option before writing here. Unfortunately, collectors join lines without line endings plus this would not work for binary data (such as shapefile, xlsx, etc.). Do you know a way to have reader transformed to BytesIO?

Comment: Which java version is used on your environment?

Comment: Generally readers in java operate with character streams opposite to IO streams, which operate with byte streams. Starting with java 9 java `InputStream` has method `readAllBytes()`, which could be called on `istream` variable and returns byte array, which could be converted to BytesIO. If your environment has java 8, it would require some boilerplate code to read all bytes from inputstream.

Comment: Hi Alexandra, thanks for an answer, your proposed solution is universal and works!

```bytes_object = io.BytesIO(istream.readAllBytes())```

```data = xr.open_dataset(bytes_object, engine='h5netcdf')```

```print(data)```